# different committees of two mathematician and one computer science major can be formed from the four mathematician and three computer science major

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

How many different committees of two mathematician and one computer science major can be formed from the four mathematician and three computer science major on the faculty of small college?

Can somebody explain to me how can I find the answer of this please?

Comment: Consider the binomial coefficient ${n \choose m}$ that gives you the number of ways to choose $m$ elements among $n$ possible ones.

Comment: To form a committee you need to select two of the four mathematicians and one of the three computer scientists.  How many ways can you select two of four mathematicians (order does not matter)?  How many ways can you select one of three computer scientists (order does not matter).  Please edit your question to indicate what you have attempted and where you are stuck.